# Using Rightclick event in angularjs directives

Tags: node.js, angularjs, treeview

I would like to use the Angular directives concept to display a popupwindow for a child node of a tree view upon a Rightclick event. Below is my sample code:

Tree.html

```
<div
  data-angular-treeview="true"
  data-tree-model="roleList"
  data-node-id="roleId"
   data-node-label="roleName"
   data-node-children="children"
   data-ng-rigtclick="onItemRightClick()" 
    data-node-children="children">
    </div>
```

treeViewcontroller.js

```
$scope.roleList1 = [
        { "roleName" : "User", "roleId" : "role1", "children" : [
          { "roleName" : "subUser1", "roleId" : "role11", "children" : [] },
          { "roleName" : "subUser2", "roleId" : "role12", "children" : [
            { "roleName" : "subUser2-1", "roleId" : "role121", "children" : [
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-1", "roleId" : "role1211", "children" : [] },
              { "roleName" : "subUser2-1-2", "roleId" : "role1212", "children" : [] }
            ]}
          ]}
        ]},

        { "roleName" : "Admin", "roleId" : "role2", "children" : [] },

        { "roleName" : "Guest", "roleId" : "role3", "children" : [] }



      ];
```

Treeview.js

```
scope.onItemRightClick= function(val)
    {
    alert(val.roleName);
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Explain what is not working for you now...

Comment: onItemRightClick function

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such a thing as `ng-rightclick`? You could use this library https://github.com/ianwalter/ng-context-menu and use the attribute `ng-contex-menu`

Comment: how to use ng-context-menu in tree foramt give sample code

Comment: Have a look at the link I posted. It has a very good instruction.

Answer (score 2):

angular-treeview directive doesn't have right click attribute exposed.

You can refer [Angular treeview git repository](https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview).

If you need this feature, you can start introducing your custom attribute in existing directive and push your changes back to git. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve a right click, you have to write a custom directive which will catch the event for you.

Here an example:

**Markup**

```
<div id="name" ng-controller='myController'>
   <button name="button" my-right-click='test()'>my button</button>
</div>
```

**The directive**

```
app.directive('myRightClick', function($parse) {
  return {
    scope: false,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var fn = $parse(attrs.myRightClick);
      element.bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          event.preventDefault();
          fn(scope, {$event:event});
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**The controller**

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   $scope.test = function() { // method is passed in by attribute
      console.log('hello from controller');
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this however the event console.log() is being triggered X amount of times based on nodes level.

So lets say i clicked on a node 4 levels deep.

It will console.log() 4 times iterating through each nodes parent.